# passing 2 parameters of undefined type to a constructor (of 2 expected)

Tags: function, boost, parameters

I have a constructor where as first 2 parameteres I would like to pass:
**ID3D11ShaderResourceView*** as a steady downloaded texture **OR**
**const CHAR*** as a filename to downlowd this texture and assign it to a class ID3D11ShaderResourceView* member (with following release on demand), but I can not understand the way I should do it correctly. it looks this way:

```
class {button
public
button() {};    
button(data1 (or texture or filname), data2 (or texture or filname), rest data....);
...
~button();
}
```

so I tried:

- templates but failed, may be cause of knowledge lack, templates
  define one type while I need a choice of 2. Varradic templates, or I didnt get them right but they mean undetermined amount of variables when I need to differ only 2 first.
- Unions but it had conflict with class variable set - said could not match const char [amount] with const char* and unions do not work with std::string.
- tried void* with typeid.name() but it always showed me "void *"

I don't want to overload constructors, becuase this will create 4+ of them barely differing one from another. Do you think boost::variant helps me in this case?  Is there any smooth and effective way to build that kind of constructor? My c++ knowledge is on beginning level, sorry if its a duplicate topic, read all it suggested to me while creating it but didn't seem to find out anything closely similar, thanks:)

**Update:**
Applied boost::any, got next results:

```
class button : public frame {
public:
    button() {};
    button(boost::any                 _texture,
           boost::any                 _hover_texture,
           ...
    };

if (_texture.type() == typeid(ID3D11ShaderResourceView*)) texture = boost::any_cast<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*>(_texture); 
if (_texture.type() == typeid(const char*)) 
{
if ( FAILED(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(gvDevice,boost::any_cast<const char*>(_texture), NULL, NULL, &texture, NULL )) )
mboxout( "loading texture failed.", "UI texture load error", true );
};

if (_hover_texture.type() == typeid(ID3D11ShaderResourceView*)) hover_texture = boost::any_cast<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*>(_hover_texture); 
if (_hover_texture.type() == typeid(const char*))
{
if ( FAILED(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(gvDevice,  boost::any_cast<const char*>(_hover_texture), NULL, NULL, &hover_texture,    NULL )) )
mboxout( "loading texture failed.", "UI texture load error", true );
};
```

Is it the only possible decision because this one seems akward for me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, when you have combinatoric explosion/tedious repetition, ***refactor your code into reusable units***.

In this case, your constructor could be just

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
button(T1 const& texture, T2 const& hover_texture)
    : _texture(load(texture)), 
      _hover_texture(load(hover_texture))
{
};
```

And all the loading logic would be inside... you guess it the `load` function. A sample implementation of that:

```
static ID3D11ShaderResourceView* load(ID3D11ShaderResourceView* v){
    return v; // just return the resources passed in
}

static ID3D11ShaderResourceView* load(char const* fname) { 
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* p = NULL;
    if (FAILED(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(gvDevice, fname, NULL, NULL, &p, NULL)))
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("loading texture failed (") + fname + ")");

    return p;
}
```

> ***Note***: *while we were at it we separated UI from business logic. You do **not** want to display messageboxes from inside constructors. Ever. You just want to notify the caller of the problem and the caller decides what to do (use another resource, try a different path, retry a download, write a warning message to the log, shut down etc.)*

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8f25d499a523870)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// mocking ID3D*
    struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView;
    enum ERROR_CODE { ERR_OK };
#define FAILED(e) (ERR_OK != (e))
    static int gvDevice = 42;
    ERROR_CODE D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(int, char const* fname, void*, void*, ID3D11ShaderResourceView**, void*) {
        std::cout << "Loaded from " << fname << "\n";
        return ERR_OK;
    }
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct frame{ virtual ~frame() = default; };

class button : public frame {
public:
    button() {};

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    button(T1 const& texture, T2 const& hover_texture)
        : _texture(load(texture)), 
          _hover_texture(load(hover_texture))
    {
    };

private:
    // TODO Rule-Of-Three constructor/destructorl 
    // SUGGEST: Rule-Of-Zero using shared pointers instead
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* _texture;
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* _hover_texture;

    static ID3D11ShaderResourceView* load(ID3D11ShaderResourceView* v) { return v; }
    static ID3D11ShaderResourceView* load(char const* fname) { 
        ID3D11ShaderResourceView* p = NULL;
        if (FAILED(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(gvDevice, fname, NULL, NULL, &p, NULL)))
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("loading texture failed (") + fname + ")");

        return p;
    }
};

#include <cassert>

int main() {
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* default_texture = NULL;
    assert(!FAILED( D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(gvDevice, "default_texture.bin", NULL, NULL, &default_texture, NULL)));

    try {

        button button1("t1.bin",        "hover1.bin");
        button button2(default_texture, "hover2.bin");
        button button3("t3.bin",        default_texture);
        button button4(default_texture, default_texture);

    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Oops: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Loaded from default_texture.bin
Loaded from t1.bin
Loaded from hover1.bin
Loaded from hover2.bin
Loaded from t3.bin
```

There's still a lot to be improved (see the comments, e.g.) but this is a start.

Comment: "I used to consider coding as a straight routine without varieties" - this is known as [Imperative Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). The code here shows _functional programming_, and a bit of object-oriented programming. Don't worry. Just don't make a mess of your code and the rest will come :)

Comment: woah, thanks A LOT for professional approach without additional includes(any.hpp), I used to consider coding as a straight routine without varieties, I clearly got your idea with "blind" usage of overloaded  protected loaders, just floating a bit in "mocking ID3D", will manage. I'll read more about errors handling in constructors and commented info -  thanks for the critical tips :) - overedited myself too much, got further as a result :)))

Comment: The section "mocking ID3D" should just be removed. It's here to make the demo self-contained, because I don't have that library